# Can gain be used to say an improvement in decreasing something? Or it's just for improving in increasing something

Tags: word-usage, usage

I know I can say

> A higher fiscal gain can be achieved by spending more wisely. (self-made sentence)

I am wondering can I use **[gain](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gain)** when the improvement is reduction in something, for example

> A higher noise (reduction?) gain can be achieved through insulating the wall using the acoustic foam.

Or an extreme example like:

> The fat loss gain can be affected by the improper eating habits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The verb **gain** can be used as a synonym for "achieve" without respect to whether the achievement is an increase or decrease.

> We can gain a considerable degree of noise reduction with a wall that is only 5cm thicker.
>
> We can gain considerable noise reduction with a wall only 5cm thicker.

And the noun **gain** can be qualified by a prepositional phrase that contains references to decrease:

> A gain in noise reduction.
>
> A gain in hearing-loss reduction  <sup>becoming "iffy"</sup>

But you should avoid modifying **gain** with a noun or noun-phrase that expresses the idea of decrease:

**fat loss gain**.

**hearing-loss reduction gain**

Comment: Eh, kind of, but I'm not sure it's really applicable in phrases like "fat loss gain", which are confusing at best.  In the case of "noise reduction", you would only ever say "noise reduction", not "noise *gain*" or even "noise reduction gain".

Comment: I've edited, changing the word **word** to **verb**.